# Skip header using Google Sheet Api with python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

I'm writing data to Google Sheets using their API. However, each time I append the document, I get an header. How can I write my data without each time getting a header.

This is my code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["a","b","c"])
df.columns = [''] * len(df.columns) 
print(df)


def Export_Data_To_Sheets():
    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID_input,
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        #insertDataOption='INSERT_ROWS',
        range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME,
        body=dict(
            majorDimension='ROWS',
            values=df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
    ).execute()
    print('Sheet successfully Updated')


Export_Data_To_Sheets()
```

I thought this was going to work, but the header seems to be added in the Export function.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How about doing just `df.values.tolist()` instead of `df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())`?

Comment: whats the result of `print(df)`? Does this contain headers? Can't you just `df = df[1:]`?

Comment: I succeeded using @kelvt solution with `[[item for sublist in df.T.values.tolist() for item in sublist]]`